Delete series from chart excel with VBA code
I want to delete series with VBA code in EXCEL2019.
My code work in EXCEL2021 but when run it in EXCEL2019, excel crashes and close suddenly.
Chart type is Bar Chart.
 Dim nameOfIBs() As String, AUM() As Long
    Dim ch as chart
    set ch= Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects("AUMChart").chart
    
        Do While ch.SeriesCollection.count > 0
          ch.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop
             With ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                  .values = AUM
                  .XValues = nameOfIBs
                  With .DataLabels
                     .NumberFormat = "[$-fa-IR,300]0"
                    With .Font
                       .Size = 16
                       .FontStyle = "Bold"
                       .NAME = "IPT.Nazanin"
                       .ColorIndex = 1
                    End With
                    
                End With
             End With


Have you tried this code on more than one file? And does Excel crash regardless of the file being tested?

Yes. tried in many files.

What type of chart is it?  See https://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html#:~:text=When%20you%20try%20to%20run%20the%20macro%2C%20however%2C%20it%20will%20crash%20on%20the%20.Delete%20line%20in%20the%20macro

It is Bar chart.

I edited my code in my post. please see it.

Hang on - you've changed the code in the question after I answered and removed the part where you show us you're using Early Binding. Nevertheless my answer still applies.

In VBA you have a choice of Early Binding:
Dim ch As chart

Set ch = Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects("AUMChart").chart

Or Late Binding:
Dim ch As Object

Set ch = Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects("AUMChart").Chart

When we as programmers interact with Excel via the Object Model if we reference the Excel DLLs and TypeLibrary then our code is Early Binded and that means its stuck & bound to a particular version of Excel.
This is why as programmers we give up the Reference to the DLL & TypeLibrary with Intellisense (at the end of development) and use Late Binding where it will work across versions of Excel.
Also put in protective programming before you delete:
If ch.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then
    ch.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
End If


It does not work.

I changed my code, but not work.
